# Entity error SQL syntax

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

here an entity :

```
namespace Siriru\GSBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="match")
 */
class Match
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $step;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Siriru\GSBundle\Entity\Player")
     */
    protected $player1;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Siriru\GSBundle\Entity\Player")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    protected $player2;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="time", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $time1;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="time", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $time2;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Siriru\GSBundle\Entity\Player")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    protected $winner;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Siriru\GSBundle\Entity\GoldsprintType", inversedBy="matches")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    protected $type;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct(Player $player1, Player $player2 = null)
    {
        $this->player1 = $player1;
        $this->player2 = $player2;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set step
     *
     * @param integer $step
     * @return Match
     */
    public function setStep($step)
    {
        $this->step = $step;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get step
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getStep()
    {
        return $this->step;
    }

    /**
     * Set time1
     *
     * @param \DateTime $time1
     * @return Match
     */
    public function setTime1($time1 = null)
    {
        $this->time1 = $time1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get time1
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getTime1()
    {
        return $this->time1;
    }

    /**
     * Set time2
     *
     * @param \DateTime $time2
     * @return Match
     */
    public function setTime2($time2 = null)
    {
        $this->time2 = $time2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get time2
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getTime2()
    {
        return $this->time2;
    }

    /**
     * Set player1
     *
     * @param \Siriru\GSBundle\Entity\Player $player1
     * @return Match
     */
    public function setPlayer1(Player $player1 = null)
    {
        $this->player1 = $player1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get player1
     *
     * @return \Siriru\GSBundle\Entity\Player 
     */
    public function getPlayer1()
    {
        return $this->player1;
    }

    /**
     * Set player2
     *
     * @param \Siriru\GSBundle\Entity\Player $player2
     * @return Match
     */
    public function setPlayer2(Player $player2 = null)
    {
        $this->player2 = $player2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get player2
     *
     * @return \Siriru\GSBundle\Entity\Player 
     */
    public function getPlayer2()
    {
        return $this->player2;
    }

    /**
     * Set winner
     *
     * @param \Siriru\GSBundle\Entity\Player $winner
     * @return Match
     */
    public function setWinner(Player $winner = null)
    {
        $this->winner = $winner;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get winner
     *
     * @return \Siriru\GSBundle\Entity\Player 
     */
    public function getWinner()
    {
        return $this->winner;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param \Siriru\GSBundle\Entity\GoldsprintType $type
     * @return Match
     */
    public function setType(GoldsprintType $type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return \Siriru\GSBundle\Entity\GoldsprintType 
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }
}
```

I generate the CRUD with `php app/console doctrine:generate:crud`

The localhost/app_dev/match/ give me :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.step AS step2, t0.time1 AS time13, t0.time2 AS time24, t0.player1_id AS player1_id5, t0.player2_id AS player2_id6, t0.winner_id AS winner_id7, t0.type_id AS type_id8 FROM match t0':

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'match t0' at line 1
```

Whyyyy ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that "match" is a keyword in SQL. You should rename your table to something else.

If you don't want to change the name of the table, try to escape it with back quotes:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`match`")
 */
```